# Insert and remove text in Table within Google Docs

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-docs

I have a Google Doc containing a 3x4 Table. I need to remove and add text in those table cells from a funciton.
[image]

I can index all table cell values with this code:

```
 var searchElement = copyBody.findElement(DocumentApp.ElementType.TABLE);
     var element = searchElement.getElement();
     var table = element.asTable();
     var tablerows = element.getNumRows();

        for ( var row = 0; row < tablerows; ++row ) {
          var tablerow = element.getRow(row)
          for ( var cell=0; cell < tablerow.getNumCells(); ++cell) {

            var celltext = tablerow.getChild(cell).getText();
            Logger.log( "Text is ("+celltext+")" );
```

The logg puts out the following:

```
[16-01-19 01:23:31:663 PST] Text is (A)
[16-01-19 01:23:31:665 PST] Text is (C)
[16-01-19 01:23:31:666 PST] Text is (E)
[16-01-19 01:23:31:667 PST] Text is (X)
[16-01-19 01:23:31:669 PST] Text is (Row 2, Cell 1)
[16-01-19 01:23:31:670 PST] Text is (Row 2, Cell 2)
[16-01-19 01:23:31:672 PST] Text is (Row 2, Cell 3)
[16-01-19 01:23:31:673 PST] Text is (Row 2, Cell 4)
[16-01-19 01:23:31:675 PST] Text is (Row 3, Cell 1)
[16-01-19 01:23:31:677 PST] Text is (Row 3, Cell 2)
[16-01-19 01:23:31:678 PST] Text is (Row 3, Cell 3)
[16-01-19 01:23:31:679 PST] Text is (Row 3, Cell 4)
```

I have used this before to insert text (free form, not in table cells):

```
function insertText() {
 var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
 var val = body.findText('Hello! R3C3');
  if(val == null)
  {
   var text = body.editAsText();
   text.insertText(9, 'Hello! R3C3');         
  }
  else
  {
    body.replaceText('Hello! R3C3','');
  }
}
```

**Question:** How can I find and replace text in e.g **Row 2, Cell 1** with **'Hello! R3C3'** ?

Comment: I tried to search for 'Row 3, Cell 3' with an for loop and logg if it finds the value in any text, without any scuccess.   for ( var ooo = 0; ooo < celltext.length; ooo++) { 
              var celz = celltext[ooo]; 
              
              
              if ( celz == 'Row 3, Cell 3' ){
                Logger.log('Found:  Row 3, Cell 3');
              }
            }

Comment: This worked, to get one specific cell value:   var table1 = table.getRow(1).getCell(1).getChild(0).getText();
 Logger.log(table1);

Comment: And this seems to set the Cell value text with another text value: var table2 = table.getRow(1).getCell(1).getChild(0);
  table2.setText('helo?! ;D');

Comment: which means your problem is solved isnt it?

Comment: No not really, i wish.. It can add text, but not replace. In my older example i could use body.replaceText which gives me an error now with tables: Cannot call method "replaceText" of undefined.

Comment: Ah, inorder to replaceText i need to use the body, like  body.replaceText instead of table.replaceText

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how i got it to work for inserting text to a specific table-cell in Google Docs:

**First 'find' the table in the Document:**

```
  var copyDoc = DocumentApp.openById(copyId);
  var copyBody = copyDoc.getActiveSection();

          var searchElement = copyBody.findElement(DocumentApp.ElementType.TABLE);
          var element = searchElement.getElement();
          var table = element.asTable();
          var tablerows = element.getNumRows();
```

**And to insert/remove text use the following:**

```
  //Row3Cell3
      var Row3Cell3 = table.getRow(2).getCell(2).getChild(0).getText();
      if(Row3Cell3 != 'Hello! R3C3')
      {
        var Row3Cell3_1 = table.getRow(2).getCell(2).getChild(0);
        Row3Cell3_1.setText('Hello! R3C3');         
      }
 else
  {
    copyBody.replaceText('Hello! R3C3','');
  }
```

So I hope this can be helpfull for others looking for similar solution.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to John, if you already have the table you need, you can edit the cell text itself via:

```
table.getRow(rowIdx).getChild(colIdx).asText().setText('Your text here');
```

Thus, in your example (Row 2, Cell 1):

```
table.getRow(1).getChild(0).asText().setText('Hello R3C3!');
```

Reference:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/table (getRow and getChild)